# What is this repo and what does it do: "signal-xenial sources.list"? And is it safe to delete?

Tags: repository

I have `signal-xenial sources.list` installed and I don't know what it does. I can see it is `xenial` and I am running on `jammy`, so I am wondering if it is safe to delete?

Thanks

Comment: You've not shown what's in it, but since you know nothing about it and also "running on jammy" :~), I'd guess it is not unsafe to delete.

Comment: Sorry about that :) This: "https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main". I am wondering if Ubuntu uses the Signal Messenger APP to encrypt emails or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signal-xenial.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is the list file for the [Signal messenger](https://signal.org) package. It is called `xenial` because it hasn't been updated since `xenial`, but it will still pull in the most recent version, which runs equally well on Ubuntu 23.04.

If you remove it, the Signal app will be removed from your system (the next time you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`). Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Will the software actually be removed, or just never get updated again? On my systems, removing a source does not cause software installed from it to be deleted.

Comment: I removed the repo manually from WinSCP and did an update and upgrade. Afterward, i did sudo apt remove signal-desktop and 445MB was removed.